# Mac - VirtualBox - VPN issue

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on Mac OS X 10.10.4. At work I use that VirtualBox named "u64" [Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit].

However when I came home and started the VirtualBox, the ubuntu was not able to resolve the DNS for my company specific FQDNS.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

[Perryg answer was spot on!](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=50368#p230224)

On my mac terminal, following command did the trick:

**`VBoxManage modifyvm "u64" --natdnshostresolver1 on`**

> NOTE - rename the **u64** with the name of your Virtual box instance.